# Uninitialized variable in case statement

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I still can't figure out how to get rid of warnings about uninitialized variables whenever I use the following structure, even though I know that this can never happen.

```
TCustomEnum = (ceValue1, ceValue2, ceValue3);

function DoSomething(LI_Enum: TCustomEnum): Integer;
var
  lNumber : Integer;
begin
  case LI_Enum of
    ceValue1 : lNumber := 1;
    ceValue2 : lNumber := 2;
    ceValue3 : lNumber := 3;
  end;
  Result := 2 * lNumber;
end;
```

> W1036 Variable 'lNumber' might not have been initialized

I found 3 solutions, but i don't like any of them. Especially with more variables or statements. Is there any other way how to avoid this?

1. Wrap function with `{$WARN USE_BEFORE_DEF OFF}` and `{$WARN USE_BEFORE_DEF ON}`
2. In every case statement use `else Exit;` with `Result := 0` on the beginning
3. Initialize every variable although the value will be never used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this compiler warning a little disappointing. After all, surely the compiler can detect that you have covered all possible values of the enumerated type. I don't believe that it should be worrying about you having put an invalid ordinal in the enumerated type, if indeed that is the thinking behind this warning.

In any case, I personally use the following helper methods to deal with this:

```
procedure RaiseAssertionFailed; overload;
procedure RaiseAssertionFailed(var v1); overload;
procedure RaiseAssertionFailed(var v1,v2); overload;

....

procedure DoRaiseAssertionFailed;
begin
  raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt(
    'A critical error has occurred:'+ sLineBreak + sLineBreak +
    '      Assertion failed at %p.'+ sLineBreak + sLineBreak +
    'In order to avoid invalid results or data corruption please close the program and report '+
    'the above error code along with any other information relating to this problem.',
    [ReturnAddress]
  ) at ReturnAddress;
end;

procedure RaiseAssertionFailed;
asm
  JMP    DoRaiseAssertionFailed;
end;

procedure RaiseAssertionFailed(var v1);
asm
  JMP    DoRaiseAssertionFailed;
end;

procedure RaiseAssertionFailed(var v1,v2);
asm
  JMP    DoRaiseAssertionFailed;
end;
```

Your code would then become:

```
function DoSomething(LI_Enum: TCustomEnum): Integer;
var
  lNumber : Integer;
begin
  case LI_Enum of
    ceValue1 : lNumber := 1;
    ceValue2 : lNumber := 2;
    ceValue3 : lNumber := 3;
  else
    RaiseAssertionFailed(lNumber);
  end;
  Result := 2 * lNumber;
end;
```

This is very similar to the approach outlined by @Dsm. If you use that approach then compiler can see that you are raising an exception, and knows that `lNumber` does not need to be initialized.

I prefer though to wrap the raising of the exception into a shared function. That way I don't need to write the same error message again and again. An application of the DRY principle.

However, if you do this, and move the raise into a shared function, then the compiler is not capable of determining that the function will raise an exception. Hence the untyped var parameters. This allows you to *mark* the variable as being potentially modified and so suppress the compiler warning.

Yet another approach would be to declare an exception class that supplied the text in its parameterless constructor.

```
type
  EInternalError = class(Exception)
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor EInternalError.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(
    '...' // your text goes here
  );
end;
```

Then your code becomes:

```
function DoSomething(LI_Enum: TCustomEnum): Integer;
var
  lNumber : Integer;
begin
  case LI_Enum of
    ceValue1 : lNumber := 1;
    ceValue2 : lNumber := 2;
    ceValue3 : lNumber := 3;
  else
    raise EInternalError.Create;
  end;
  Result := 2 * lNumber;
end;
```

Comment: I guess it is horses for courses, but I don't find the warning disappointing. I do understand your point of view - it is one I used to hold myself. But the compiler cannot sensibly resolve all possibilities, for example lNumber := TCustomEnum( x ); where x is some ordinal type. So I guess they err on the side of caution.

Comment: @Dsm My argument is that such a cast needs to check the range of the ordinal value. Failure to do so is an error at that point. To expect the rest of the code to defend against that is simply not realistic. For instance, how do you feel about `Proc[enum](foo)`? Here `Proc` is an array of procedures, indexed by an enumerated type. By your argument am I right in thinking that your code would look like this: `if not InRange(enum, low(enum), high(enum)) then raise Exception.Create(...); Proc[enum](foo);`?

Comment: @Dsm I think that the only sane way to deal with this is to validate any external data at the boundary, and then trust that the data is valid from there on.

Comment: No, David, my argument is that you cannot guarantee that the enum contains a valid value. I don't really care whether the error should have been corrected somewhere else - it might not be my code or any code I have access to.

Comment: In this case I agree with David. It is well shown in the example of array of procedures. There is always a place for a programming error and how to get illegal values, but I don't like, when I'm forced to always deal with it. if I covered all enum values, I would expect that nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 6):

By doing something like the following

```
function DoSomething(LI_Enum: TCustomEnum): Integer;
var
  lNumber : Integer;
begin
  case LI_Enum of
    ceValue1 : lNumber := 1;
    ceValue2 : lNumber := 2;
    ceValue3 : lNumber := 3;
    else raise exception.create('Oops I forgot one of the LI_Enum values') 
  end;
  Result := 2 * lNumber;
end;
```

Perhaps a better exception text or even not raising an exception at all (and assigning a different value to lNumber), but raising an exception does have the benefit of prompting you if, say, six months down the line you add a new case value.

### Edit

The point really is that the compiler is correct. The underlying structure for an enum is some form of (unsigned) integer so it is perfectly possible for the enum to contain an illegal value, say 27, for example. There are lots of ways this can arise in practice. So you need to cater for that possibility if you are writing complete code. The compiler is just warning you that you have not catered for that possibility.

Comment: The point is that the warning is always displayed, even when I have all values. Maybe it's a problem only for older versions of Delphi.

Comment: @Triber No, all versions are affected. The reality is that lNumber could be assigned an illegal value, so you need to cover that case, and the best way, in my opinion, is raising an exception.

Comment: I really don't agree with your final paragraph. If an enumerated type variable has a value that is invalid, then that can only be due to a programming error.  It's unrealistic to expect code to defend against such things. If you did then every single line of code would be affected.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well yes, programming error is the most likely cause, but none of us is perfect and that particular error can be hard to find. I have fallen into this trap, so I guess that colours my view. And my code (and yours) does guard against such things in this type of case. But whether it is really programming error can be a moot point, particularly when files and databases are involved.

Comment: When the data comes in externally, the programmer's task is to make sure it is valid. Once it has passed that test and crossed the boundary, it can be trusted.